# Constructor OpenCV is undefined

Tags: opencv, image-processing, processing

Trying to learn Face Recognition via Processing2 using OpenCV. This code is copied right out of Jan Vantomme's book. However, I am using an updated version of OpenCV from that listed in book. Error received is: The constructor(sketch_ORIGopenCV) is undefined. Does anyone know if OpenCV is not upward compatable, or what causes this error ?

```
import gab.opencv.*; //original code in Vantomme's book shows "import hypermedia.video.*;"
                     // I assume thats updated to gab.opencv.* but should still work.
OpenCV opencv;

void setup()
{
  size( 640, 480 );
  opencv = new OpenCV( this );       //  <-----THIS IS THE ERROR LINE*********
  opencv.capture( width, height );
}  

void draw()
{
  opencv.read();
  opencv.flip( OpenCV.flip_HORIZONTAL );
  image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 );
}
```

Comment: processing has a long history of wrapping only limited/outdated opencv functionality. be wary of that. if you really want to use current opencv from java, - skip the processing layer !

Comment: btw, you're most probably talking about face-*detection* (face, or not?), not face-*recognition* (who is it?), different pair of shoes.

Comment: Also having this problem.